# ignoring upper case words with explode() in PHP

Tags: php, explode, case-sensitive

I'm new to PHP and I'm trying to explode data in a text file and put it into an array, then a table. The data in the text file looks like this:

THE MAN IN THE HIGH CASTLE by Philip K. Dick published 1965 born 1922

Assume that you cannot alter the original data. If I write:

```
$dataArray = explode(" ",$book);
```

that works for most of the data, but but splits every word of the book title into a different element. Is there a way I can tell it not to split upper case words?

Comment: No. You need to write something custom for this. PHP does not have a function for *everything*.

Comment: Explode on `' by '` then explode again...

Comment: Almost everything...  Looking at that data I would start by detecting the position of ' by ' in a case sensitive manner.

Comment: Or stop using `explode` for everything, read up on regexps instead of workarounds.

Comment: Explode is case sensitive...if you put a letter or string containing letters in the function as the delimeter rather than a space. Space doesn't have case differentiation.

Comment: @developerwjk, that is why I changed the title.  I thought it was misleading

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `explode`, you may want to try using [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) for this. It splits strings using a regular expression:

```
$book = 'THE MAN IN THE HIGH CASTLE by Philip K. Dick published 1965 born 1922';

// Split on all-lowercase words
print_r(preg_split('/\b\s*[a-z]+\s*\b/', $book));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => THE MAN IN THE HIGH CASTLE
    [1] => Philip K. Dick
    [2] => 1965
    [3] => 1922
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = explode("by", $book);
$title = $input[0];
$stuff = $input[1];
```

Comment: If you know the title is always capitalized, then a regex might work better.